# Python exectuable: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2]: No such file or directory matplotlibrc

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyinstaller

I have a python script that I want to convert into an executable. It makes use of the matplotlib module, which apparently is causing the isue. I've created the exe file with "pyinstaller --onefile file.py". When I open the .exe file in the distr folder, this is what it shows and then immediately closes:
[image]

Im sorry for posting an image but I had to record the screen in order to actually see the message  (i'm not that much into programming to know other way)

The code for my program is the following:

```
OPTION=input("Corriente de salida del prefraccionador es destilado o residuo? (D/R)")

from pylab import*

WF=100
xZ=0.68
WE=50
xF=0.2
xF2=[0.0]*10

ZNA1=0.3
ZNA2=0.4
ZNA3=0.6
T1BB=350
T1BD=320
T2BB=350
T2BD=320


DSEA=[0.0]*len(xF2)
DSEB=[0.0]*len(xF2)
for i in range (0,10,1):
    if OPTION=="D":
        xF2[i] = i / 10
        WA1D = WF * (xZ - xF2[i]) / xZ
        WA1B = WF - WA1D
        WA2D = WA1B * xZ
        WA2B = WA1B + WE - WA2D
        WA3B = WA2B - WA1B * (1 - xZ)
        WA3D = WA2B - WA3B
        EDA1 = WA1D * ZNA1
        EDA2 = WA2D * ZNA2
        EDA3 = WA3D * ZNA3
        DSEA[i] = (EDA1 + EDA2 + EDA3) / (WF)
    else:
        xF2[i] = i / 10
        WA1B = WF * (xZ - xF2[i]) / xZ
        WA1D = WF - WA1B
        WA2D = WA1B * xZ
        WA2B = WA1B + WE - WA2D
        WA3B = WA2B - WA1B * (1 - xZ)
        WA3D = WA2B - WA3B
        EBA1 = WA1B
        EDA2 = WA2D * ZNA2
        EDA3 = WA3D * ZNA3
        DSEA[i] = (EBA1 + EDA2 + EDA3) / (WF)


    # 2 COLUMNAS
    # Caudales
    WB2B = WE
    WB1B = WF * (1 - xF2[i]) + WB2B
    WB1D = WF * xF2[i]
    WB2D = WB1B - WB2B
    # Eficacias de carnot
    ZNB1 = (T1BB - T1BD) / T1BB
    ZNB2 = (T2BB - T2BD) / T2BB
    # Eficacias de columna
    EDB1 = WB1D * ZNB1
    EDB2 = WB2D * ZNB2
    # DSEB
    DSEB[i] = (EDB1 + EDB2) / (WF)
xFL=[xF,xF]
xFT=[0,1]
plt.ylabel="DSE"
plt.xlabel="Fraccio molar entrada"
#plt.plot(x,y)
plt.plot(xF2,DSEA)
plt.plot(xF2,DSEB)
plt.plot(xFL,xFT)
plt.legend(["Amb prefraccionador","Sense prefraccionador","Composició entrada"])
plt.show()
```

In case you want to try, it should display the following plot for an input "D" (irrelevant):
[image]

I have written two other programs without importing any module to see if that was the issue, and both the .exe and .py files work as intended (one of them has even a tkinter GUI which works fine) on the computer they were written and in another one that hadn't python installed.

I've searched posts related to this error but I can't find a solution as they all are related to ordinary .py files failing, which is not my case as my .py file is working.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
[I found the solution here](https://groups.google.com/g/pyinstaller/c/IfyyRcj1pGk).
The problem is that the versions of pyinstaller and onefile don't work together.
Use

> pip install --upgrade pyinstaller

in the terminal and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar error and was able to resolve it by uninstalling the outdated version of Pyinstaller (pyinstaller-5.6.2-py3-none-win_amd64.whl) using the following command:

```
pip uninstall pyinstaller
```

Next, I installed the latest version of Pyinstaller (pyinstaller-5.7.0-py3-none-win_amd64.whl), which was uploaded on 2022-12-04 15:02:37, using the following command:

```
pip install --no-index --find-links=C:\DriverPy\LibrariesandInstall\Py_3_10_7_64bits pyinstaller
```

Note: The path C:\DriverPy\LibrariesandInstall\Py_3_10_7_64bits in the above command is the location of my folder containing all the wheel libraries.

I used the --no-index and --find-links flags to prevent Pyinstaller from searching the index for the latest version and to specify the exact location of the wheel file.